# How to add files to iPhone SE

Tags: music, rhythmbox, iphone

I'm trying to add music to my new iPhone on Ubuntu 16.04.

I guess Rhythmbox is capable of doing this? I have Rhythmbox open and I plug in my iPhone but it doesn't show up. It shows up in the file browser but there's no files in there.

It looks like I might need the libimobiledevice package? I type `sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice6` but it says it's already installed. And I read somewhere this package isn't even up to date anyways.

I'm afraid to keep trying things. I don't want to install packages that I don't need because I don't want to have unnecessary problems and I don't feel confident removing them completely.

I would imagine this is a pretty common problem? I mean, we all have phones, and we all probably want music on them. It's weird because I can't find any straight-forward answers.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: By the way, I'm running iOS 10.

Comment: You need iTunes and that software is available for MacOS and Windows only. Do not waste your time trying to do in anywhere else.

Comment: I don't believe that is correct. (Note: It's disgusting how corporate giants refuse to support compatible software due to being afraid of the free and open-source revolution.)

Comment: Also if I must get a virtual system or run iTunes through WINE then I will. But I don't believe that is actually necessary. I've read of people having success with libimobiledevice. I just haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: It's a matter of facts, not faith. Read: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-iphone-6.html . Quoting: (...) *let's no forget that there is NOT going to be any real way you can sync your stuff onto an iPhone 6 without using iTunes. That's an illusion we must destroy right from the beginning.*

Comment: It doesn't work with Wine either. You can install and run iTunes but it won't connect to the phone.

Comment: I don't need it to do everything perfectly. I just want to put music on it. I really have to go buy a mac or Windows license in order to put songs on my iPhone?

Comment: You can try the tips in the blog post linked above.

Answer (score 0):

I have a pain in the neck work around because i have an iphone se and run linux and don't purchase my music from the itunes store (I have many cds and record my own music). Anyways, I've managed to successful put music on my iphone se by installing windows vista through virtualbox and then using copytrans manager. I would imagine this method would work with any version of windows ie XP or 7. you can download virtualbox from the software manager but I'll put a link to their site and copytrans, hope this helps maybe.
https://www.virtualbox.org/
https://www.copytrans.net/